# Highcharts load before the dialog has opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a dynamic highchart that is shown in a dialog on a click event. I am close to where I want to be on this, with the exception of the following:

**1:** My chart has an event: load included, which means the chart is loaded before the click event. I want it to load on the click event. My first instinct was to place the highchart code in the onclick event, but that had unexpected impacts on the chart rendering itself. How can I have the chart load on the click event without impacting the chart behavior?

**2:** The left hand side of my chart does not disappear from the chart, as shown in the jsfiddle example from the highcharts website: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/ and I do not see any difference between the example and my code that would impact this. How can I have my chart copy the example and have my points disappear on the left?

**3:** When my chart has reached the end of the data array, I want it to start over, but instead it seems to keep running without data, eventually flatlining. My dataset includes 3 arrays, each of 40 elements; apiData, calculatedData (both numbers), and apiDate (universal time values). How can I have the chart run a continuous loop on my data?

Example of my data:

```
var apiData = [75, 76, 89, 91, 86, 56, 46, 89, 87, 96];
var calculatedData = [78, 81, 98, 95, 89, 70, 59, 91, 90, 78];
var apiDate = [1482613200,1482624000,1482634800,1482645600,1482656400
,1482667200,1482678000,1482688800,1482699600,1482710400,1482721200];
```

These divs have the onClick event attached:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left col-xs-4" 
       id="8d450007-9cbf-11e6-a7da-14109fd4bd8b"> 
  </div>
  <div class="center col-xs-4" 
       id="8d45001c-9cbf-11e6-a7da-14109fd4bd8b">
  </div>
  <div class="right col-xs-4" 
       id="8d450008-9cbf-11e6-a7da-14109fd4bd8b">
  </div>
</div>
```

Dialog that contains the chart:

```
<!-- Div to hold the line chart -->
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <div id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></div>
</div>
```

Dialog setup:

```
//Initialize the dialog and set options
var opt = {
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  width: 660,
  height:460,
  title: 'Hourly Temperature'
};
var theDialog = $("#dialog").dialog(opt);



var divIdList = ["#8d45001c-9cbf-11e6-a7da-14109fd4bd8b", "#8d450007-9cbf-11e6-a7da-14109fd4bd8b", "#8d450008-9cbf-11e6-a7da-14109fd4bd8b"]
$(function () {
  divIdList.forEach(function(id) {
    $(id).click(function () {
        theDialog.dialog('open');
    });
  })
});
```

Highchart code:

```
$(function () { 
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        Highcharts.chart('canvas', {
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, 
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function () {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each 3 seconds
                        var series1 = this.series[0];
                        var series2 = this.series[1];
                        var seriesCount = 0;
                        setInterval(function () {
                            var x = (new Date(apiDate[seriesCount] * 1000)).getTime(),
                                y1 = apiData[seriesCount],
                                y2 = calculatedData[seriesCount];
                            series1.addPoint([x, y1], true, true);
                            series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
                            seriesCount++;
                        }, 3000);
                        if (seriesCount > 10) {
                          char
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Date/Time'
                },
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            }
            ],
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'API Temperature data',
                data: (function () {
                    // use api predicted data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date(apiDate[0])).getTime(),
                        dataCount = 0,
                        i;

                    for (i = 0; i <= 40; i ++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time,
                            y: apiData[dataCount]
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            },
            {
                name: 'Calculated Temperature data',
                data: (function () {
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date(apiDate[0])).getTime(),
                        dataCount = 0,
                        i;

                    for (i = 0; i <= 40; i ++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time,
                            y: calculatedData[dataCount]
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }
            ]
        });
});
```

I would really appreciate some help on this. Maybe it is really simple but I have been staring at it so long now, I'm driving myself crazy.

Comment: 1) 
                        $("#dialog").on('dialogopen', function() {
                        setInterval(function () {
                            var x = (new Date(predictedTempDt[seriesCount] * 1000)).getTime(),
                                y1 = predictedExtTemp[seriesCount],
                                y2 = predictedIntTemp[seriesCount];
                            series1.addPoint([x, y1], true, true);
                            series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
                            seriesCount++;
                        }, 3000);
                    })

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and next time try to trim the code and fit it to a specific question.

1. You should create the chart on click event, so the load event will take place after the modal shows up.
2. The data you provided is incorrect. Timestamp is not valid and it is not sorted ascending.
3. Because the data must be sorted, you have to clean the data and start over from the beggining. Use series.update(), series.remove or series.setData([]) to delete the data. https://jsfiddle.net/3cqnrp48/